# LCD I2C 16x4 can't print / display characters

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

I want to display text on my lcd I2C using arduino uno, but the lcd just blink then not showing the text.

I've change the LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27); to LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F); but the lcd not responds.

i follow this schema [image]

Here is my arduino code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27);


    void setup()   /*----( SETUP: RUNS ONCE )----*/
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      lcd.begin(16,4);

    // ------- Quick 3 blinks of backlight  -------------
      for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
      {
        lcd.backlight();
        delay(250);
        lcd.noBacklight();
        delay(250);
      }
      lcd.backlight();


      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Hello, world!");
      delay(1000);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("HI!YourDuino.com");
      delay(8000);  

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Use Serial Mon");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Type to display");  


    }


    void loop()
    {
      {
        if (Serial.available()) {
          delay(100);
          lcd.clear();
          while (Serial.available() > 0) {
            lcd.write(Serial.read());
          }
        }
      }

    }
```